# bash+xmlstarlet: How can one index into a list, or populate an array?

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to select a single node using xmlstarlet from the following example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="key.xsl" ?>
<tables>
  <tableset>
    <table name="table1">
      <row>
        <fld name="fileName">
          <strval><![CDATA[/my/XYZ/file1]]></strval>
        </fld>
        <fld name="fileName">
          <strval><![CDATA[/my/XYZ/file2]]></strval>
        </fld>
        <fld name="fileName">
          <strval><![CDATA[/my/other/XYZ/file3]]></strval>
        </fld>
        <fld name="worksBecauseUnique">
          <strval><![CDATA[/XYZ/unique]]></strval>
        </fld>
      </row>
    </table>
  </tableset>
</tables>
```

I'm trying to build an associative array in bash... How can I select a single node, or iterate over multiple nodes using xmlstarlet?

I'm trying something like the following so far which is not working:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name=\"fileName\"]/strval[0]" xmlfile.xml
```

Hoping to get "/my/XYZ/file1" however this is not working.

Comment: Can you assume that there will never be newlines in the content?

Comment: Also... associative? With what as key?

Comment: As you probably noticed, this is related to my other post.  There should not be new lines contained within the CDATA values.  My hope is to be able to modify each CDATA value individually.

Comment: CDATA is just syntactic sugar -- a text node is a text node is a text node, whether its contents are given with CDATA or with character-by-character entity escaping.

Comment: Associative in that the key=//fld[@name] and value=//fld[@name]/strval

Comment: But then how do you deal with a name having multiple values?

Comment: Do you want to separate them (with something like newlines) in the content side of the shell array?

Comment: Note that that's dangerous -- UNIX paths can contain literally any non-NUL character, *including* newlines. Letting a maliciously-constructed path be read as two paths, the latter anchored off your filesystem's root, isn't necessarily safe.

Comment: Exactly, and this is where I'm stuck.  I'm fine if the attribute is unique however when there are multiple attributes with the same exact name which yield multiple values, I'm having trouble.  For example, fileName is giving me trouble because it has more than one value and each value must be unique.

Comment: You need to decide on a data representation, there, or use a more powerful language (one that lets you use lists or arrays as dictionary values, for instance). That's not really a bash language question as much as it is a question for you about what your data model looks like.

Comment: I've amended my answer to show one pattern, but for the reasons above it's not a *good* pattern.

Comment: ...although, really, if your goal is to extract content for modification, then I'd think the easiest thing would be an indexed array rather than an associative one; that way the multiple like-keyed items still stay fully separate, and you can use the index values in your later query to actually apply changes.

Comment: I'd also seriously consider rewriting what you're doing here to use `xmlstarlet pyx` rather than `xmlstarlet ed`; it's a far better tool for round-tripping.

Comment: Thanks. this gives me plenty of food for thought

Comment: BTW, if my answer on your other question is sufficiently inadequate that you need a follow-up question... could you explain why? Over there, as a comment on the answer? :)

Comment: (Also, would you consider it accurate if I edited the title of this question to "bash+xmlstarlet: building a bash array from query results"? Right now, the title doesn't seem to do a great job of representing your actual goal).

Comment: Sure... it could be changed to that.  I would also like to know how to select a single node within a range.  I can do a count on fileName and get 3 back, but was hoping to also be able to retrieve the strval by using an index.. .if that makes sense?

Comment: If there's a thing you're missing here, it's that XPath arrays are 1-indexed, not 0-indexed. Thus, getting the first entry is foo[1], not foo[0].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the first part of your question, there's a simple mistake you're making:

```
strval[0]
```

needs to be

```
strval[1]
```

...to select the first instance, as XPath arrays are 1-indexed, not 0-indexed.

---

Now, when you want to select the second match inside your whole document, not inside the parent `fld`, that looks a bit different:

```
(//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name="fileName"]/strval)[2]
```

---

Now on to populating a shell array. Since your content here doesn't contain newlines:

```
query='//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name="fileName"]/strval'

fileNames=( )
while IFS= read -r entry; do
  fileNames+=( "$entry" )
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "$query" -n xmlfile.xml)

# print results
printf 'Extracted filename: %q\n' "${fileNames[@]}"
```

You aren't giving enough detail to set up an associative array (how do you want to establish the keys?), so I'm doing this as a simple indexed one.

---

On the other hand, if we were to make some assumptions -- that you wanted to set up your associative array to match from the `@name` key to the `strval` value, and that you wanted to use newlines to separate multiple values when given for the same key -- then that might look like this:

```
match='//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name][strval]'
key_query='./@name'
value_query='./strval'

declare -A content=( )
while IFS= read -r key && IFS= read -r value; do
  if [[ $content[$key] ]]; then
    # appending to existing value
    content[$key]+=$'\n'"$value"
  else
    # first value for this key
    content[$key]="$value"
  fi
  fileNames+=( "$entry" )
done < <(xmlstarlet sel \
           -t -m "$query" \
           -v "$key_query" -n \
           -v "$value_query" -n xmlfile.xml)
```

Comment: Thanks this definitely helps... I may be stuck moving to something other than bash to get the job done.

Comment: If you described what the job was in more detail, it might be possible to be more helpful. If your goal is to do edits on the shell side and then apply them, that's definitely very, very doable -- though not with very good efficiency without making significant compromises to correctness or terseness. If you want a language optimized for doing complex operations on XML documents, might I suggest XQuery?

Comment: Ok... last question I asked you stated I used too much detail. Thanks for your suggestions... I have a very complex task of modifying a very complex xml file.  I can describe what I'm trying to do, but it would take a lot of explaining.

Comment: "Detail" is indeed the wrong word. "Context", perhaps? One of the useful things about context is that it can be provided separately from a core problem statement -- ie. clear and terse problem statement over here, contextual information over here, context not required to answer and clearly separated.

Comment: Re: the context-vs-detail thing, a different piece of the "How to Ask Smart Questions" guide applies: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal ("describe the goal, not the step").

Comment: Ok, trying to be concise. The goal is to be able to create a flat file of key=value pairs from in.xml.  Then, I need to be able to modify the flat file to key=new_value.  The flat file is then used to rename values contained in in.xml and generates out.xml.  I have this entire process working except when I run into multiple values that have the same attribute name.

Comment: I'd suggest putting sigils in the keys, ie. key[1], key[2], etc; as long as that doesn't overlap with literal key values.

Comment: Was thinking the same... however still unable to pull individual vals using `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name=\"fileName\"]/strval[2]" file.xml` - this is not working

Comment: `//tables`, by the way, looks for elements named `tables` throughout your entire document. It's wildly inefficient compared to just rooting in `/tables`.

Comment: Why do you insist on using double quotes outside the query, by the way? Makes your life harder because it means you need to escape the literal double quotes inside the query.

Comment: Anyhow -- it doesn't work because you're putting the `[2]` in the wrong place; it's looking for the second `strval` inside that single `fld`.

Comment: Edited the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Removed outside double quotes and using `/tables` instead of `//tables` however still cannot pull value when using `xmlstarlet sel -t -v /tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name="fileName"]/strval[2] file.xml

Comment: This worked: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "(//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name=\"fileName\"]/strval)[2]" file.xml` - I needed to wrap the XPath in quotes or I get a syntax error.  Thanks!

Comment: Look at how my code uses quotes -- single quotes on the outside and double quotes on the inside, vs double quotes in both places.